# c++ не правильно определяет цвет пикселя

Tags: c++, color, экран

Я пишу простого бота который определяет цвет и нажимает на кнопки если цвет изменился, но С++ не правильно его определяет

```
int B;
HDC hdc_ = GetDC(NULL);
COLORREF color;

for (; ;)
{
    color = GetPixel(hdc_, 894, 368);
    B = GetBValue(color);
    cout << B << endl;
}
```

При смене цвета в указанных координатах цвет не изменяется, но когда я перемещаю консоль в какое-то другое место он изменяется, хотя координаты указаны не там куда я переместил консоль. При выполнении такой программы в python или java проблем не возникает

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что такое "закрываю точку". Пример явно не достаточен. он лишь получает некий пиксель, судя по названию функций и выводит один их его компонентов. И кстати, C++ не может не правильно определить цвет. Ибо для него все числа. А если число не то, что вы ожидали, отлаживайте по шагам вашу программу. Или задавайте более развернутый вопрос, с указанием большего количества подробностей. Что бы его можно было выполнить и получить тот же неожиданный результат, что и вы

Comment: В указанных координатах при смене цвета он не выводиться в консоль. Когда я перемещаю консоль по экрану, я нахожу какую-то точку в которой с++ берёт цвет, но это не те координаты которые я указывал. При выполнении нажатия координаты определяются правильно, но при определении цвета они по какой-то причине находятся в совсем другой точке

Comment: Скомпилировал, проверил - работает. Именно с указанными координатами. Вы координаты экрана используете при проверке?...

Comment: Да, я использую координаты экрана которые перед этим проверил

Comment: может второй дисплей подключен?

Comment: Нет, подключен только 1 монитор, к сожалению я не могу здесь прикрепить видео как работает этот код

Comment: Может включено масштабирование экрана?

Comment: Все настройки экрана стоят по умолчанию. При выполнении нажатия на координаты, они определяются правильно, но при проверке цвета они определяются с какого-то другого места